# NSCollectionViewItems are not visible

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I am trying to show items in a subclass of NSCollectionViewItem in an NSCollectionView. I can see that the NSCollectionViewDataSource gives the right number of items and is called the right number of times

```swift
extension Document: NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.attachedFiles?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let attachment = self.attachedFiles![indexPath.item]
        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "AttachmentCell"), for: indexPath)
        item.imageView?.image = attachment.thumbnailImage
        item.textField?.stringValue = attachment.fileExtension ?? ""
        return item
    }
}
```

but the items are not shown in the GUI. I check that item.view.isHidden is false, but is there anything I need to do to make the items visible? Of course, there is also the possibility that they are never added to the collection even though the data source functions are called, but in that case my question would be how to fix that?

Comment: Did you set collectionViews dataSource? if you do, you can use breakpoint to check whether `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection)` is called and `attachedFiles` is empty. If you did not set, just set :)

Comment: The data source is connected and the functions are called. I can insert elements into `attachedFiles` and I get the right number (and when looking at the text field in the items I create, I also have the right content). As far as I can see the only thing wrong is that the items are not shown in the window.

Comment: try doing this --> `var attatchedFiles: [Array] { didSet { collectionview.reloadData() } }`. You probably are not reloading. Just a wild guess

Comment: I do call reloadData() and the NSCollectionViewDataSource functions are called, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: You're not giving much details for us to help you. Appart from "wild guesses" on usual traps... Would be better if you could set e.g. a github repository.
However, in the list of "usual traps", have you made sure that the size of the created item is not (0,0) ?